# False Unused "private" methods should be removed

Tags: java, sonarqube

I think we have false positive in our Sonar's installation (5.6 and java plugin 4.0).
An Unused "private" method should be removed issue is raised for the following code :

```
public boolean orderLineHasDetails(OrderLine orderLine) {

        boolean result = orderLine.getContractDevices() != null && orderLine.getContractDevices().size() > 0;

        if (result) {

            result = asLeastOneUniqueId(orderLine.getContractDevices());

        }

        return result;

    }


    private boolean asLeastOneUniqueId(List<ContractDevice> contractDeviceList) {


        Iterator<ContractDevice> contractDeviceIterator = contractDeviceList.iterator();

        boolean result = false;

        while (!result && contractDeviceIterator.hasNext()) {

            result = StringUtils.isNotBlank(contractDeviceIterator.next().getDeviceUniqueId());

        }

        return result;

    }
```

Is this a known bug ?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
A new false positive inner a method :
[image]

Regards,

Stephane

Comment: Yes it's for a java sources with the latest java plugin (4.0)

Comment: What is the exact return type of `orderLine.getContractDevices()` ?

Comment: This problem still exist in version 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the previous sonar installations. But recently it is fixed and working fine. Try using `sonar Lint` from eclipse market place (I hope you are using eclipse) which is the latest release of sonar in eclipse.

I tried this code in my code base and the message is not displayed. So try updating `sonar` or `sonarqube` to `sonar Lint`.

Comment: I don't use eclipse and my goal is that work in a jenkins job ;)

Comment: It is May 2017 and I am still getting lots of false alerts of that kind :-(